# Combining separate date time fields to one date_time field

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I used the following R code to create a POSIXct date time field from a separate date and time field both in character format using lubridate and dplyr.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
c_cycle_work <- tibble(
  StartDate = c("1/28/2011", "2/26/2011", "4/2/2011", "4/11/2011"),
  StartTime = c("10:58", "6:02", "6:00", "9:47")
)

c_cycle_work %>%
  mutate(start_dt = paste0(StartDate, StartTime, sep = " ", collapse = NULL)) %>%
  mutate(start_dt = mdy_hms(start_dt))

# 1 1/28/2011     10:58   2020-01-28 11:10:58
# 2 2/26/2011      6:02   2020-02-26 11:06:02
# 3  4/2/2011      6:00   2020-04-02 11:06:00
# 4 4/11/2011      9:47   2020-04-11 11:09:47
```

The start_dt field I created is in Y m d format even though I used mdy_hms based on the data.  Also, all years have been changed to 2020.

Went over this several times, used paste vs. paste0, etc. but still stumped.

Comment: Dates and the date part of datetimes are always printed in their ISO format in R. The reader function is for the input format, not output.

Comment: Is there any relation between changing integers to strings and the question? Shouldn't you edit the title?

Comment: I was searching for something related to that earlier.  How do I change the title?

Comment: Title edited. I copied and pasted from your comment to the answer by @MrFlick.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the `paste0()` which doesn't have a `sep=` argument. So when you paste the date and time you get `1/28/201110:58` and it spilts that into `1/28/20/11/10/58` though it seemed to work differently with my version `lubridate_1.6.0`. Also you where use "hms" but your times didn't have seconds. This should work with your data

```
c_cycle_work %>%
  mutate(start_dt = paste(StartDate,  StartTime, sep=" ")) %>% 
  mutate(start_dt = mdy_hm(start_dt))

#   StartDate StartTime            start_dt
#       <chr>     <chr>              <dttm>
# 1 1/28/2011     10:58 2011-01-28 10:58:00
# 2 2/26/2011      6:02 2011-02-26 06:02:00
# 3  4/2/2011      6:00 2011-04-02 06:00:00
# 4 4/11/2011      9:47 2011-04-11 09:47:00
```

Comment: The question title is from a search I used earlier.  I want to change it to.  Combining separate date time fields to one date_time field.